# how do I get the class/property/etc associated with a .NET attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, class, attributes

If I apply a custom attribute to a class, for example:

```
[Foo]
class Bar {}
```

It's clear that when I retrieve my Foo attribute instance, that it's associated with a Bar. Inside the Foo implementation, say in the ctor, how do I get the class associated with the instance of the attribute? So far, all I've been able to come up with is putting it into the ctor of the attribute:

```
[Foo(typeof(Bar)]
class Bar {}
```

which seems horribly redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass it in.  See this answer...

[How do I get the member to which my custom attribute was applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168942/c-custom-attributes-how-to-get-the-member-type-to-which-an-attribute-was-appl/2169373#2169373)

Answer (score 4):

When you are actually using Foo, you should have the class Foo is an attribute of. So if you need to access a property in Foo, you can pass the Type/instance in as an argument.